# Sensor memory - sel error

Tags: memory, sensors

I have a SEL error, checked all system no sel error logs.

`[root@terter ~]# ipmitool sel list
SEL has no entries`

Fans power suplly looking normal too

`[root@terter ~]# ipmitool sensor list -v
Sensor ID              : Fan 6 Presence (0x40)
 Entity ID             : 29.6
 Sensor Type (Discrete): Fan
 States Asserted       : Availability State
                         [Device Present]

Sensor ID              : Power Supply 1 (0x41)
 Entity ID             : 10.1
 Sensor Type (Discrete): Power Supply
 Sensor Reading        : 40 Watts
 States Asserted       : Power Supply
                         [Presence detected]
`

The only problem that i found, sensor memory reading error:

`[root@terter ~]# ipmitool sensor list -v
....
Sensor ID              : Memory Status (0x4c)
 Entity ID             : 7.2
 Sensor Type (Discrete): Memory
 Sensor Reading        : 0 error
 States Asserted       : Memory
                         [Presence Detected]`

Should i change the ram, how can i be sure that i have no memory error.
Any tool checks memory ?